# Using functions from a different class to connect signals

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Hello I am making a program and I am using a stackedLayout to show different "areas" within the program.  I want to use classes to "separate" functions related to certain areas.  For instance Area1 has a start button and a clear button and When the start button is pressed it runs the program, when the clear button is pressed the area is cleared. When I define the functions to start and clear within my main class the buttons work fine, but when I call them from another class nothing happens.

***main.py***

```
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, Interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        run = hello()
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(run.hello1)
        self.clearButton.clicked.connect(run.hello2)

class hello(object):
    def hello1(self):
        print "start button"

    def hello2(self):
        print "stop button"
```

May someone please explain why nothing is being printed when I click on the buttons?

Comment: How are you calling them from the other class?  Are you calling them on the correct instance of `hello`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to classes.  What do you mean by "the correct instance"?

Answer (score 2):

You are not keeping a reference to your `hello` instance. So it's garbage collected after `__init__` ends and is not available when you press your buttons.

Try storing it as a instance attribute (`self.run`), rather than local variable (`run`):

```
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, Interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.run = hello()
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.run.hello1)
        self.clearButton.clicked.connect(self.run.hello2)

class hello(object):
    def hello1(self):
        print "start button"

    def hello2(self):
        print "stop button"
```